# How to build asp.net core stack from source?

Tags: powershell, asp.net-core

I am trying to build asp.net stack from source, i followed instruction documented [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Universe) but when running build command i ended up with `The module '.build' could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module .build'.` error message.I googled for the issue but with no luck.Could anybody shed some light on this?

Here is an attachment from powershell console :
[image]

Comment: did you tried `./build.ps1`, `./build.sh` if under nux or `build.cmd` on windows ?

Comment: i am using windows.it suggested me to do `./build.ps1` for security reason and i did accordingly.

Comment: what is the command you use ? did you try as admin ?

Comment: as i mentioned i use `./build.ps1` command inside the `Universe` directory and yes i do run as admin.

Comment: what if you try build.cmd ?

Comment: exact same result

Comment: tried to launch build.cmd in a command promt, not in powershell, I'm able to build it on win7

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125889/discussion-between-behnam-esmaili-and-agua-from-mars).

Comment: hi . you should import module first in Powershell . run you're powershell as administrator and type  Set-ExecutionPolicy bypass -Force . then import you're modules .

Comment: @arashzgh could you please clarify a little bit more?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Because if you want to just debug it is usually much easier just to replace a package reference with a project reference for the dependency you want to debug.

Comment: @pawel my main intention was to figure out whole pipeline of ASP.NET core application , to Infer how the server (IIS , kestrel ,...) finds the startup class of our application and runs it.could you please introduce me some related articles?

Comment: I would start from the docs here: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/. Here is the code to find Startup: https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/StartupLoader.cs#L66

Comment: @pawel your links helped me a lot , thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @pawel: using the Univese 1.0.0 release zip I had failures trying .\build.ps1. But the steps worked:(1).\build.ps1 pull (2).\build.ps1 complile, (3).\build.ps1 install. compile step ran to completion but failed on UserSecrets repo (now in Configuration). install step failed on  UserSecrets repo. The build pulled 1.1.0~ artifacts,not sure why, but think this would explain the UserSecrets fail. Initial build attempts failed on "git log origin/dev..origin/release".  I'm using the GitHub.appref-ms --open-shell installed from https://desktop.github.com/. Initial failed builds, dev and 1.1.0-preview